# Remove Doctrine life cycle event from within a Symfony2 controller

Tags: model-view-controller, events, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I am looking to remove a [Doctrine Extensions life cycle event listener](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Tree/TreeListener.php) from within a controller.

I need to remove the listener for update events because I need to update all nodes in the tree at once. Something that is not supported by the library, but is possible by directly setting the correct left, right, level etc...

Is it possible to remove a life cycle even from within a controller? What is a possible solution for this situation.

I thought something like this might work, but it did not

```
$evm = $em->getEventManager();

$listener = new \Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener();
$evm->removeEventListener( array( 'postUpdate' ), $listener );
```

Comment: FWIW in 2016, using single root & `NestedTreeRepository::persistAsLastChildOf` on all children I was able to achieve bulk update without removing the listeners. The code is under 10 lines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes it will work, but there are different events used:

```
$listenerInst = null;
$em; /* entity manager */
foreach ($em->getEventManager()->getListeners() as $event => $listeners) {
    foreach ($listeners as $hash => $listener) {
        if ($listener instanceof WantedListenerClass) {
            $listenerInst = $listener;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
$listenerInst || die('Listener is not registered in the event manager');
// then you can remove events you like:
$evm = $em->getEventManager();
$evm->removeEventListener(array('onFlush'), $listenerInst);
```

Comment: I tried it with all of the events in the array and they are still firing.

Comment: Events added with annotations directly in the entity does not appear in these events listeners, any idea who to disable them ?

Comment: you cannot disable them through listeners, the only way would be to modify metadata directly, see `$em->getClassMetadata($entityClassName)->lifecycleCallbacks`

Comment: Be aware that the same listener can be attached to more than one event and it can be the same instance. In that case consider removing the listener inside the `if` statement and don't use `break` after doing so. For example use this `$evm->removeEventListener($hash, $listener);`